# How to select the first TD elements in a Row

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have table with some rows.
I would like to create a CSS that allow me to change the color for the first `TD` element in a `TR` row recursively only for a table which has the class `mytable`.

Could you give me a sample of CSS?

```
<table class="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>Event Title:</td><!--Change color here-->
        <td>{EventTitle}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Start date:</td><!--Change color here-->
        <td>{DateTimeStart}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>End date:</td><!--Change color here-->
        <td>{DateTimeEnd}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can use **:first-child** property. Write like this:

```
.mytable td:first-child{
 color:red;
}
```

Comment: does all the browsers support this?

Comment: I need to apply only to the class="mytable", how can I do it? thanks

Comment: Write like this **.mytable td:first-child{}**

Comment: `.myTable td:first-child{color:red;}`

Comment: @sandeep: "till" means "from some old version until this new version, but not any newer version". You meant to say something like "It works *starting from* IE7."

Comment: @BoltClock thank for the clarification & it's useful. May be it's better if i write "till IE7 & above".

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS "first-child" element: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

So can do something like:

```
.mytable td:first-child {
   something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as @sandeep has written you can use first-child to achieve the goal. Better approach, if possible, is to add a class name to your first td. If this is supposed to be the header, you might also want to use th instead of td

Comment: how would that be better approach? getting the code dirtier is a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Sandeep has the right idea, but you seem to be asking for a style rule that's slightly more specific. Try this:

```
table.mytable td:first-child {}
```

Answer (score 0):

`:first-child` does not work in IE, a practical approach would be to change these `td` which you are gonna apply a background to `th` and then style them

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

***HTML***

```
<table class="mytable">
                <tr>
                        <td>Event Title:</td><!--Change color here-->
                        <td>{EventTitle}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Start date:</td><!--Change color here-->
                        <td>{DateTimeStart}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>End date:</td><!--Change color here-->
                        <td>{DateTimeEnd}</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
```

***CSS***

```
.mytable tr td:first-child{
 color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hrBAn/1/